# How to only let a user access a virtual machine and not the host machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I have friends that are *very* bad at following directions.

I would like to allow them to use the internet from my home, however I am very tired of cleaning up Viruses and randomly downloaded games.  I'm sure anyone with kids also has this type of problem.

Is there a way I can make a login that only allows access to a virtual machine (does not allow any changes to the host account?)

Thanks,

-Eric

Comment: How are they accessing the VM? By remote desktop or by physical console access?

Answer (score 4):

You could use local policy on the host to lock them out. [Here](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/introduction-to-windows-7-policy-local-user-security-policy/) is a good article on Windows 7 Local User Security Policy.

Comment: Would you care to explain what the basic steps or tools are that are used in the article?

Answer (score 0):

A different solution to your problem, you can use a software like Deep Freeze that will cleanse your system of its past on reboot. However, Deep Freeze is not free software and you can look into alternatives http://alternativeto.net/software/deep-freeze/

[Windows SteadyState](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=d077a52d-93e9-4b02-bd95-9d770ccdb431&displaylang=en) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a XP or Vista machine I would recommend Windows SteadyState as birukw mentions over a VM which is overkill.  I used it in the past for my mothers laptop who would let anyone come over use and would just get bogged down with malware. SteadyState lets you set up a user that is very much locked down and with almost no write permissions and once they log off anything that was written is wiped.  A while back Hak5 did a great Ep in which they showed up setting up a system that is locked down, http://www.hak5.org/episodes/episode-411.